# Spring Security - Escaping XSS output

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm currently working on an already existing web application , and I had to add spring-security to something that is already there.

I know that ESAPI could to the trick, but right now, i really need to use the spring framework.

So I found "some" XSS vulnerabilities that I need to escape on output only. The data is stored in a database, and then it's displayed.

There is the problem, when I use

```
  <c:out value="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name}"/>
```

everything works fine. But I'd like to not use this for each output, and find something quicker. ( I have something like 20K output , and I don't really have time to escape every output right now )

So I found this link : https://jeevanpatil.wordpress.com/2011/07/22/prevention_of_xss/ , and added

`<context-param>
<param-name>defaultHtmlEscape</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>`

to my web.xml file. But this is not working (unless this is to escape user input and not output ?)

So here is the question. Is there any way to escape the output to block XSS, without doing it 1 by 1 ?

Comment: Can't you just use `${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name} ` without `<c:out` ?

Comment: If the userPrincipal.name is an XSS attack, let's say <script>alert('aaa');</script> , then on display, the browser will dispaly the alert

Comment: How do you output those unescaped values? Do you use some JSP tag? If yes, which tag?

Comment: The whole line without any escaping is `<h1> Hello ${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name} </h1>`